# Why does changing an array seems to lead to infinite loop in React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, components, headless

I have a component that adds suggested articles at the bottom of an article. By default, the suggested posts are just pulled from the most recent posts in that current post's category. However, in the WordPress backend (it's a headless CMS with a Frontity front end), the article author can select up to a couple suggested posts, which if selected, will get added to the beginning of that default array. That array is then used to render out a list of 7 posts.

However, the moment I use unshift to add to that array, I get the following error:

> react-dom.development.js?61bb:14997 Uncaught Error: Too many
> re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite
> loop.*

Here's the component below:

```
const MoreArticles = ({ state }) => {

  const data = state.source.get(state.router.link);
  const postId = data.id;
  //Get the current post's data
  const post = state.source[data.type][postId];

  const categoryID = post.categories[0];
  const categoryName = state.source.category[categoryID].name;
  const categoryLink = state.source.category[categoryID].link;
  
  const catData = state.source.get(categoryLink);
  
  const catPosts = catData.items;

  let morePosts = catPosts;

  const selectedPostIds = post.meta_box.post_relatedPosts;

  let selectedPosts = []; 

  if(morePosts && selectedPostIds){
    selectedPostIds.map((postId) => {
      const selectedPost =  state.source.post[postId];
      const selectedPostObj = (selectedPost) && {type: 'post', id: postId, link: selectedPost.link};
      selectedPosts.push( selectedPostObj );
    })
  }
  

  if(morePosts && selectedPosts){ 
  //THIS SEEMS TO BE THE LINE THAT'S CAUSING AN INFINITE LOOP
    morePosts.unshift(selectedPosts);
  } 

 
  const filteredCatPosts = ( morePosts ) ? morePosts.filter(item => item.id !== postId  ) : [];



  return(
    <>
    { filteredCatPosts && 
      <MoreArticlesContainer className="col-12">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-8">
            <h3><IoFlashSharp />You might also like</h3>            
            <ArticleList articles={filteredCatPosts.slice(0, 2)} />
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-4">
            <H3>More from {categoryName}</H3>
            <ArticleNumberedTextList posts={filteredCatPosts.slice(2, 7)} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </MoreArticlesContainer>
    }
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please add the entire component. Also, modifying objects in any way in react is bad practice and can lead to errors like this.

Comment: We need more code, but basically you're mutating an array that's used as a prop/state or something, and doing so causes it to re-render. Then you check for it to exist and it enters a loop. It modifies, tries to re-render, hits that if check, unshifts, and so on. It is important to notice that an assignment of an array is NOT a copy - it assigns the pointer. Use spread syntax like [...] or do a deep copy, slice, map, whatever you wanted that copies an array instead of direct assignment like `let morePosts = catPosts;`

Comment: Thanks guys, I added the full component. @KonradLinkowski you mentioned not modifying object in react. What would the alternative be, knowing that I need to create/modify an object at some point?

Comment: Create a new object and copy all the properties e.g. `{ ...obj }`

Comment: @Nikki9696 thanks for pointing that out, I am still learning and knowing that is very useful